# DialogResult WPF

Tags: wpf

I am reading one book which says

> Rather than setting the DialogResult
>   by  hand after the user clicks a
>   button, you can designate a button as
>   the accept button (by setting
>   IsDefault to true). Clicking that
>   button automatically sets the
>   DialogResult of the window to true.
>   Similarly, you can designate a button
>   as the cancel button (by setting
>   IsCancel to true),  in which case
>   clicking it will set the DialogResult
>   to Cancel.

This is the MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="400" Height="400">
    <StackPanel>

        <Button Name="BtnShowDialogStatus" Click="BtnShowDialogStatus_Click">DIALOG RESULT</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code for click event:

```
private void BtnShowDialogStatus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(new NewWindow().ShowDialog().ToString());
}
```

And this is the Dialog box which I am opening on the click event:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationWPF.NewWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="NewWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Name="BtnDEfault" IsDefault="True" Click="BtnDEfault_Click">DEFAULT BUTTON</Button>
        <Button Name="BtnCancel" IsCancel="True" Click="BtnCancel_Click">CANCEL BUTTON</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

This is the code for it:

```
private void BtnDEfault_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}

private void BtnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

I can see it returning the DialogResult only as false no matter I click the default or cancel button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> IsDefault ties the button to the Enter key, so that pressing the Enter key will fire the Click event. It does not mean that the Yes button will return true for the DialogResult.

Refer to the links.It will clear up things for you

http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2010/03/22/getting-a-dialogresult-from-a-wpf-window/

http://www.wpftutorial.net/Dialogs.html

Hope it helps...

Comment: First link is broken :(

Answer (score 6):

change your code to

```
private void BtnDEfault_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = true;
    this.Close();
}

private void BtnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = false;
    this.Close();
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Hi, U didnt read the author's words.He says that DialogResult automatically gets set.

Comment: I tested this just now, and the dialog result doesn't automatically get set for either button.  What is weird, however, is that the button set as IsDefault does not close the Window automatically when clicked.  The button set as IsCancel, however, DOES.  Anybody else seeing this weird behavior?

Comment: I should clarify that a bit.  If you don't specify any handlers (or don't specify the DialogResult value in either handler), then the button with IsCancel set will still close the Window.  The button set with IsDefault will NOT.  But if you set the DialogResult in both event handlers, then the Window will close (and you don't even need the this.Close() line).  Very weird and very inconsistent.

Comment: yes Mike Loux, I completely agree with you. It's very inconsistent.

Comment: You do not need to call `this.Close()`. Setting the `Window.DialogResult` property to true or false automatically closes the dialog/window. (at least in .Net 4.5 - I'm a newcomer)

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding setting IsDefault as true and IsCancel as false only enables you to assign what event should occur i.e. the window will fire close event on 'Escape' key for IsCancel and for Enter key for IsDefault=true.

You will need to set the Dialog result from your button click / command action handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Using net 5 this seems to be all the code needed to open a ShowDialog window, and close it.

From the window you have opened.

```
   <Button Margin="10"   IsDefault="True"  Click="Ok_OnClick" >OK</Button>
   <Button  Margin="10" IsCancel="True">Cancel</Button>

    private void Ok_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = true;
    }
```

From function to open window.

```
        var requester = new DeleteRequester();// a wpf window       
        var showDialog = requester.ShowDialog( );
        if (showDialog != null && showDialog.Value)
```

the only reason it is checked for null is to get rid of the blue nag line from re-sharper.

It seems whenever you change the "DialogResult" The window is going to close and the value gets returned. Kind of make sense, why would you change the value if you weren't done.

With what ever your doing with the window, you simply need to close the window to return a false result, or set the DialogResult to true to close the window with a true result.

Simple and basic:

```
 If(ItWorked){DialogResult = true;}// closes window returns true

 If(ItsJunk){Close();}// closes window returns false
 If(ItsJunk){DialogResult = false;}//closes window returns false
```