# C# How do I get Apply button to keep window open?

Tags: c#, xaml

I use `this.Show` from Main() to show this window and add content to it dynamically, but the window closes immediately after opening. So, I used `this.ShowDialog` and I want to code an Apply button to allow the user to test the parameters without closing the window. Accept or Cancel close the window.

Here is the code:

```cs
ShowMyWindow()
{
    Button applyButton = new Button();
    applyButton.Content = "Apply";
    applyButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler((obj, e) =>
    {
        DialogResult = true;
    });
    stackPanelEight.Children.Add(applyButton);

    Button acceptButton = new Button();
    acceptButton.Content = "Accept";
    acceptButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler((obj, e) =>
    {
        DialogResult = true;
        this.Close();
    });
    stackPanelEight.Children.Add(acceptButton);

    Button cancelButton = new Button();
    cancelButton.Content = "Cancel";
    cancelButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler((obj, e) =>
    {
        DialogResult = false;
        this.Close();
    });
    stackPanelEight.Children.Add(cancelButton);

    return (bool)ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Hey there! To help others helping you, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Don't set the dialog result in the event...

Comment: @Ron Beyer, I am having difficulty with your response. Could you please be more specific? I've spent the last 7 hours trying to figure this out and I'm stuck. Yes, I'm new to C# and could use a bit more help.

Comment: I replaced the DialogResult in the event handlers with a local bool rCode, so acceptButton.Click sets rCode=true. Then I modified the code _return (bool) ShowDialog()_ to _rCode=(bool)ShowDialog(); return rCode;_

When I click on the Accept button, rCode is set to true inside the Click event, the dialog is Closed (this.Close) but as soon as that happens rCode returns from the call to ShowDialog as false despite having set it to true inside the event handler. I do not understand this behavior.

Comment: I want to point out that you can format code blocks with triple back ticks (```) before and after the code in question. Having a language tag (C#) will provide syntax highlighting to your code blocks.

Comment: @John Doe Oh...thank you!!...I was wondering how to add code to messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that my Main window was a subclass of Window, so I had no need to use `ShowDialog`; `app.Run` did that for me. I was trying to be too fancy by using a call in my Main to a bool Method.

Here is what I did to solve my problem:

```
applyButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler((object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
{
    CollectThePolygon();
    ProduceZmathCode();
});

acceptButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler((object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
{
    CollectThePolygon();
    ProduceZmathCode();
    Close();
    Environment.Exit(1);
});

cancelButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler((object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
{
    Close();
    Environment.Exit(1);
});
```

Comment: I am honored by accepting my answer, but your answer solves the question and should be accepted. Could you please edit your question and/or answer with information that would be vital for future users having this issue, such as the information from your comment on my answer, and then accept it instead?

Comment: Yes, I will modify and accept my answer. I believe it was a combination of the comments here including both yours and @Ron Beyers that made me think more carefully about the use of `Show.Dialog` and why I was using it. I backed up and created a simple program that did essentially nothing, and then realized the Window class was displaying the window and I did not need to use `Show.Dialog`. Your comment about scope made me think...I finally decided to simplify the code and put the actions inside the EventHandlers

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to C#, J W! The comment asking for a minimally reproducible example was probably said because a lot of WPF problems are caused by how two things interact:

1. the code containing the window's layout (.xaml)
2. the code containing the window's logic (.xaml.cs and/or .cs. This is highly debatable subject when you get more into WPF).

Without knowing both pieces of the puzzle from you, here is my attempt to help...

Your code states `Button applyButton = new Button();` , goes on to modify that local button, but you never show a statement like `myWindow.Children.Add(newBtn);` . Without this statement, your button is declared locally but never attached to the window and will thus never show up or affect your window in any way. If you are using this structure, you probably have / would want something like this:

.xaml:

```
<Window>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Name="applyButton"/>
        <Button Name="acceptButton"/>
        <Button Name="cancelButton"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

.xaml.cs or .cs:

```
Button applyButton = (Button)this.FindName("applyButton");
applyButton.Content = "Apply";
applyButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler((obj, e) =>
{
    DialogResult = true;
});
// repeat for acceptButton and cancelButton
```

I do not use the above structure frequently. I can't give you  a reason; I guess I just learned to rely on .xaml more. I use this structure instead:

.xaml:

```
<Window>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Click="Apply_Button_Click"/>
        <Button Name="acceptButton"/>
        <Button Name="cancelButton"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

.xaml.cs:

```
private void Apply_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = true;
        }
```

Your confusion at the use of a local rCode seems to me as a scoping error. If your code says:

```
acceptButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler((obj, e) =>
{
    rCode = true;
});
```

And not `bool rCode = true;`, I simply do not understand what it does. It may be easier to visualize in my structure:

```
private void Apply_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rCode = true; // Will not compile: Undeclared variable!
}
```

If you ARE using `bool rCode = true` , well changing that variable will not affect your outer variable `rCode = (bool) ShowDialog();`, so you will always return false.

Your first statement of how using this.ShowDialog does not immediately close the dialog after opening but this.Show does... please shows how the function containing this.ShowDialog is called, I guess? ShowDialog just means it is modal; you cannot click off it to the window that "owns" it. Show means it is non-modal; you can click back to your owning window. This problem cannot be deduced from the information you have given so far.

I tried to figure out Ron Beyer's comment `Don't set the dialog result in the event` , as well as you ;). According to [this StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536988/dialogresult-wpf), I think he was stating a best practice, and not a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help.I do not use XAML since I build dynamic interfaces (seismic data and well log data) on the fly. I do have calls to Children.Add (did not show them in an attempt to reduce the code I displayed). I've solved my problem! My Main window is a subclass of Window, so I had no need to use the ShowDialog; app.Run does all that for me. I was trying to be too fancy by using a call in my Main to a bool Method. I removed that and now simply run my code (two methods that collect parameters and write zmath code) inside my event handlers Apply and Accept.  Again, thank you!